# New techniques of text classification nlp

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I have to make a text classification program with new techniques (Not using "bag of words" and "TF-IDF").
I read about EDA but I was confused.
Any ideas?

Comment: what does EDA means?

Comment: @DavidBatista Easy Data Augmentation

Comment: then maybe explain what is it (pointers to papers) and describe what you already tried and what you would like to achieve